# Template argument deduction

Tags: c++, linq, templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm currently facing a problem I haven't been able to solve myself.
Basically what I'm trying to do is implement some linq-like behaviour in C++.

I'll start off with the code in my header:

```
template<typename T, template<class = T> class A,
         template<class = T, template<class=T> class = A> class C>
class queryable
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef A<value_type> allocator_type;
    typedef C<value_type, allocator_type> container_type;    // (1)
    typedef queryable<T, A, C> type;
    queryable(container_type const &) { }
    template<typename _Out> queryable<_Out, A, C> select(/* some delegate */);
    // more methods etc
}
```

And this is how I'd like it to be instantiated:

```
std::vector<int> my_vec;
queryable<std::vector<int> > q(my_vec);
```

Needless to say this doesn't work (otherwist I wouldn't be here :) )

Now the even stranger part is that even this doesn't seem to work:

```
std::vector<int> my_vec;
queryable<int, std::allocator, std::vector> q(my_vec);
```

As you can see (by looking at the select function), it is important to me to not just use something like this:

```
template<typename T> class queryable;
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this? And is this even possible?

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: the errors I'm getting:

```
../entry.cpp:19:58: error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T, template<class> class A, template<class, template<class> class<template-parameter-2-2> > class C> class failproof::collections::queryable’
../entry.cpp:19:58: error:   expected a template of type ‘template<class, template<class> class<template-parameter-2-2> > class C’, got ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
../entry.cpp:19:61: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

EDIT 2:

As far as I understand the compiler is complaining about C not taking 2 class arguments, but 1 class argument and 1 templated class argument (1), because I defined C to be that way.
Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question, it might help : [how to ask about code that doesn't work](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code)

Comment: @VJovic I have edited my question as per your suggestion, however english is not my native tongue and I don't really know how to express my particular findings in a proper way.

Comment: I meant : post a full example, not just bit and pieces. From your question, I see it is possible to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a general method to 'explode' a type to test if it was created by a template, and to extract the types that were passed to that template. It is also possible to access the template itself and pass other parameters to it if you desire.

`vector` is a *class template*. When you apply parameters to it, you get something like `vector<int>`, which is a *template class*. A *template class* is a specific type, like any other type, it just happens to have been created via a class template.

The goal is, given a type `T`, to test if it is a *template class*, and if so to gain access to the *class template* that was used to create it, and also to access the parameters that were passed to the *class template*. In this sample, I just test for whether something is a one-arg or two-arg template, but the technique can easily be extended.

(Technically, `vector` is a two-arg template. There is a default for the second parameter, so `vector<int>` is actually `vector<int, allocator<int> >`, but it's still basically a two-arg template, not a one-arg template.)

The best place to start is with this [sample code I've put on ideone](http://ideone.com/5q2KE). I'll copy the Exploder code at the end of this answer.

I begin with

```
typedef list<int> list_of_ints;
```

and proceed to use the `Exploder` template to access all the above information. For example, `Exploder<list_of_ints> :: type_1` is the first parameter that was passed to the template, in this case `int`. The second parameter (this is the defaulted parameter) is `allocator<int>` and is accessible with `Exploder<list_of_ints> :: type_2`.

```
typedef Exploder<list_of_ints> :: type_2  should_be_an_allocator_int;
```

Given this second type, which we know was created by a template, we can access its parameter type, `int`, with `Exploder< should_be_an_allocator_int > :: type_1`, but it's more interesting to actually access the `allocator` template instead and pass a different parameter to it. This next line evaluates, in this example, to an `allocator<double>`.

```
typedef Exploder< should_be_an_allocator_int >
           :: rebind<double> :: type should_be_an_allocator_double;
```

So, even if your `list<...,...>` type did *not* use the default allocator, you can access the allocator that was used, and also any *class template* that was used to create the allocator type.

Now that we have a suitable allocator, we can go back to our original *template class* `list<int>` and replace `int` with `double`:

```
Exploder<list_of_ints> :: rebind<double, should_be_an_allocator_double> :: type
```

To verify all this has worked, the sample code uses `typeid(...).name()` to print the actual type of the various objects, along with the correct type that it should be. You can see that they match.

(Also, some templates are such that their parameters are not types, but other *class templates*, or even other *template templates*. It should be possible to extract all that, but I'm not going to look into that here.)

(One last interesting technical note. Some types, such as `allocator`, have something called `rebind` to allow this sort of access. But the technique used above works for all template classes, even those without their own `rebind`)

### The full code for the template Exploder

See [sample code I've put on ideone](http://ideone.com/5q2KE) for a full demo.

```
template <class>
struct Exploder;

template<class T, template<class> class Template>
struct Exploder< Template<T> > {
        static const char * description() { return " One-arg template. Arg 1 is a type "; }
        typedef T type_1;
        template <class V>
        struct rebind {
                typedef Template<V> type;
        };
};
template<class T, class U, template<class,class> class Template>
struct Exploder< Template<T,U> > {
        static const char * description() { return " Two-arg template. All args are types, as opposed to being (unapplied) templates. "; }
        typedef T type_1;
        typedef U type_2;
        template <class V,class W>
        struct rebind {
                typedef Template<V,W> type;
        };
};
template<class S, class T, class U, template<class,class,class> class Template>
struct Exploder< Template<S,T,U> > {
        static const char * description() { return " Three-arg template. All args are types, as opposed to being (unapplied) templates. "; }
        typedef S type_1;
        typedef T type_2;
        typedef U type_3;
};
```

Comment: To be honest, I actually like this approach! Especially since I won't need the class templates anymore, since these exploder structs provide a rebind possibility. I'm not gonna mark this one as the answer, but you are definitely getting +1 from me! Also I'll keep you informed on my progress if you like to :)

Comment: You sire are god! Not only did this work perfectly, it also showed me (once again) the true power of c++ templates. I'm not sure if it's the right this to do, but I'm marking this as the answer to my question instead of the solution posted by Mike Seymour. Thank you once again for your efforts in putting this together :)

Comment: No problem! C++ truly is a remarkable language. I'm glad to have had the chance to experiment with this and put this answer together. I only learned the principles behind this a few weeks ago, and I love applying it on StackOverflow! You can also do this with function types, using `template<class T, class A1> struct Exploder<T(A1)> { ... };` to explode the return value and argument of a function type.

Answer (score 6):

The second template parameter of the standard containers (the allocator) is a *type*, not a *template*, so you need to change your third parameter to something like

```
template<typename, typename> class C
```

(Note that the default arguments in your template parameter specifications don't serve any purpose, so I omitted them here.)

Then you should be able to instantiate the template as

```
queryable<int, std::allocator, std::vector>
```

You may be better off just parametrising over the container type, and then using its `value_type` and `allocator_type` definitions:

```
template <typename C> class queryable
{
public:
    typedef typename C::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename C::allocator_type allocator_type;
    typedef C container_type;
};
```

(One downside is that you can't directly access the allocator *template*; however, you can use the allocator *type*'s nested `rebind` definition if you need to instantiate that template for other types.)

Also, `typedef iterator const const_iterator;` is wrong; that declares an *unmodifiable* iterator that *can* be used to modify the sequence, while `const_iterator` is supposed to be a *modifiable* iterator that *can't* be used to modify the sequence.

Comment: Thank you for this, this solved the issues :) Also, about the const_iterator: I don't understand exactly what you mean. If I declare a `const iterator`, and the `operator value_type * ()` is non-const, isn't it impossible to modify the sequence?

Comment: @TomKnapen: Yes; but in that case it's also impossible to modify the iterator itself, so it can't be used as an iterator. A definition like `queryable_iterator<const T>` might be suitable.

Comment: @TomKnapen, A C++ reference might be a useful analogy. You can use the reference to modify the data it's pointing at. But you *cannot* get the reference to point at anything else; during its lifetime a reference is tied to exactly one object. And `iterator<T>` is like a pointer, and an `iterator<T> const` is a little like a reference.  (Shameless plug: By the way, check out my answer which allows more concise usage `querable< vector<int> >`)

Answer (score 1):

(A note on terminology. `vector` is a *class template*, i.e. without any parameters. And `vector<int>` is a *template class*, i.e. a class almost like any other except that it was created by a template.)

It is possible to use it as you wish, where queryable takes one template parameter:

```
queryable< vector<int> > q;
```

This means that `querable` is a template with just one parameter:

```
template <typename T>
struct queryable;
```

You then use a *specialization* that has more than one parameter:

```
template <typename ValueType, template<class T,class = allocator<T> > class ContainerTemplate>
struct queryable< ContainerTemplate<Contained> > {
        typedef ValueType value_type;
        typedef ContainerTemplate<ValueType> container_type;
        typedef typename container_type :: allocator_type A;
        // typedef ContainerTemplate <WhateverOtherValueTypeYouWish> ...
        // typedef A :: rebind <SomeOtherType> ...
};
```

The last two lines, commented out, show how you can use `ContainerTemplate` as a *class template*, creating other types as required. `ContainerTemplate` is `vector` or `list` or `set` or something like that.

As @MikeSeymour has pointed out, the use of `rebind` might be the way to access the allocator *class template*.

Sample code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Cqw0s)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Although, as I have pointed out in my question, I need access to the container type and allocator type, without the template parameters applied (I want to be able to define those myself in my class). As far as I can tell by looking at your code, it works the other way around: instead of 'exploding' the templates, it is 'imploding' them.

Comment: (I've now renamed Temp to ContainerTemplate), In this class, `ContainerTemplate` provides what you are looking for, the (unapplied) container template. It is the exploded version of the container. i.e. `ContainerTemplate` is `vector`. I'm not sure about allocator though, I think Mike is right that `rebind` would be required.

Comment: @TomKnapen, I've written another answer, which uses the same idea, but is written more generally to demonstrate how it explodes the type to access all the ingredients that went into making that type. The ingredients are the types passed to the template, also we have access to the template itself allowing us to pass in different parameters. Any feedback appreciated.